How to use a PropertyGroup inside the Preferences?
I would like to create a PropertyGroup and use it to store some preferences.
A list of folders with some additional information for each folder. There will be a ReScan button to check for updates in the folder structure and the changed values should be stored in the Add-Ons preferences and not in a Blender file.
Both bpy.types.AddonPreferences and bpy.types.PropertyGroup are classes on their own.
How can I use a PropertyGroup in a way that it is saved with the preferences?
Can I use a PointerProperty pointing to a PropertyGroup outside of the preferences class? Will the changes be saved with the preferences?
